# NsNotificationCenter is not working

Tags: swift

Actually i'm new in swift i got stuck here,Anyone can solve this Problem. actOnSpecialNotification Func is not calling on fireNotification in ViewController.swift

> In ViewController.swift

```
 func fireNotification() -> Void {
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
 #selector(vikas.updateNotificationSentLabel), name: 
 NSNotification.Name(rawValue: mySpecialNotificationKey), object: nil)
}
func updateNotificationSentLabel() {
    print("sent")
}
```

> in SecondVC.swift

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
 #selector(ViewController.actOnSpecialNotification), name: 
 NSNotification.Name(rawValue: mySpecialNotificationKey), object: nil)
}
func actOnSpecialNotification() {
    print("listen")
}
```

Comment: Your `fireNotification()` doesn't fire anything, there's only an observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all add Observer to your FirstViewConroller.

## FirstViewConroller

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClassName.methodOfReceivedNotification(_:)), name:”test”, object: nil)
```

Now, add the relevant selector method in same ViewController which will be called once the notification will be fired.

```
func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: Notification){
        //Take Action on Notification
 }
```

Now, you can fire the notification using below  lines which will call the above method which resides in FirstViewController

## SecondViewController

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(“test”, object: nil)
```

Comment: if we fire notification from firstviewController to SecondViewController without going on secondview first time